# Java instruction for clear screen on Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm looking for a method to clean the java screen. I program on Visual Studio, on Windows, and since as a terminal it uses the Windows cmd I use this instruction to clean the screen:

```
try {
        new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor(); 
 } catch (InterruptedException e) { } 
 catch (IOException s) { }
```

If i undestund well, this instruction call command 'cls' from cmd and clean the screen. But this instructuion not function on Intellij. It print a strange character (a kind of question mark). Do i must use this instruction in a different way? Or there is another instruction for clean the screen on Intellij?

Comment: Generally I find that IDE output windows are fairly simple stream implementations, with no fancy formatting like clearing the screen.  I think you'll have to test this when the app is actually running, on the terminal you intend to use.